# Passing values in Pending Intents Android

Tags: android, android-intent, background-process, android-pendingintent

Can we pass the arguments in a pending intent for the Background Process..

```
  Intent ij = new Intent(context,DemoActivity.class);
  PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0,ij,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(y, m, d,hr, mi);
  long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time,operation);
```

In this, i'm using the alarm manager for starting the background process. By using this method, can i pass any variables or arguments?

```
public class DemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
/** Creating an Alert Dialog Window */
    AlertDemo alert = new AlertDemo();

    /** Opening the Alert Dialog Window */
    alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "AlertDemo");       
}
}
```

And in Alert Demo class i just use an alert box..
Now help me, where to place the Put Exatra method?..

Comment: I think you can pass values with your Intent **ij**.

Comment: @Gowri shankar, i have edited the answer check

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can pass variables in pending Intent like the following:

```
            Intent in = new Intent(context, DemoActivity.class );
            in.putExtra( "notification_id", REGISTER_NOTIF_ID);  
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            in.putExtra("2", Variable);
            in.putExtra("1", Variable);
            in.putExtra("IMData", Variable);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, 0);
```

and do the following in your onCreate of your DemoActivity class:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    userGetId = extras.getString("2");
    userNameRecv = extras.getString("1");
    userFriendId = extras.getString("IMData")
```

Comment: Please note that this answer also shows the correct way to add the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, which was used incorrectly in the question.

Comment: yeah exactly, i observed that one

Comment: How can i receive or fetch the variables in the next activity(background process)!..

Comment: By this i am not getting any intent value infact i am getting null in bundle